# Webpack , babel error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Facing an **Unexpected Token** error on **=** after state, when compiling code using webpack. My code is as follows:

```
class GroceryItem extends React.Component {
    state = {
        labelValue: "Hello Pages"
    };        
    render() {
        return ( < div onClick = {
                this.state.labelValue
            } > ded

            <
            /div>);
        }
    }
```

I have tried various methods I found on StackOverflow, but none seems to work.

**.bablerc**

```
{
   "presets" : ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

**.webpack..config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js/');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components');
var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/main.jsx',
  output: {
  path: BUILD_DIR,
  filename: 'bundle.js'
 },
module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx?$/,
        include : APP_DIR,
        loader : 'babel',
        query:{
            presets: ['react']
        }
      }
    ]}
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `babel-preset-stage-x` preset to declare class like that.
See this [repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEDiBOB7YBTeBPAkgFxQW2hQA9cA7AExgCUUxhsA6AYUTwAdFSVTtoBvALAAoaKOgRsYXNAC8_YWMXRwAIxQgAamBABXFAC5oAIgAS6kImgAFMAHMUEIwrEBfANxKxz0fG7k0ABQAlPIintC-2DrwpNAB0AA80OQAlgBu0JxMICnAANayoeHF0NgAFikQDBJSKAyq6lq6KN4lLtAAfMko5MKtxQn94QD0qWkdQW5Doi6tLkA&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false)

```
{
    presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]

}
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Thanks. To natall stage to just run `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-2`

Comment: yeah, glad it helped.